# Android: проблема с авторизацией vk.com

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Пишу мобильный клиент vk.com, используя implicit flow. Для авторизации и получения токена, необходимо перейти по ссылке, ввести логин и пароль на сайте и нажать ок (использую WebView). После этого пользователь перенаправляется на другую страницу. В адресе той странице как раз есть токен, который мне так нужен. Как его можно получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему вам надо перехватывать переходы в `WebView` через `WebViewClient`.

```
WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "overrideUrlLoading with URL: " + url);
        if (url.contains("token=")) {
            //например токен у вас в адресе начинается после "token="
            //значит надо помешать переходу на этот адрес, вернув true
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
```

Comment: Попробую, спасибо:)

Comment: Работает! Ещё раз спасибо:) Заапрувил ваш ответ:)